# Assign a letter a numerical value in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to assign a certain amount of letters a numerical value, that can later be added together?

Ex:

```
A,B,C = 1
D,E,F = 2
```

So that if I add `A` + `D` + `D` I get `5?`

I would post what I tried, but I don't even know what I could try in this sitation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do

```
A = B = C = 1;
D = E = F = 2;
```

Comment: Is this the most flexible way? For example: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/Drjjm/ Is it possible to add the letters up after it splits them from the string so that they, in this case, equal 4?

Comment: @Charlie: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/hBW8w/ but please be consistent with variable names case

Comment: "please be consistent with variable names case" Yes, I was sloppy on that, thanks for pointing that out. What exactly does `window[curr]` mean, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @Charlie Every global variables exist in the `window` object, so `window['A']` is the global variable `A`.

Comment: Okay. And in this part, `return prev + window[curr];`, it takes the previous letter and adds it to the next one?

Comment: @Charlie Yes, it's a way to calculate the sum.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a property map to assign the values:

```
var map = { A:1, B:1, C:1, D:2, E:2, F:2 };
console.log(map.A+map.D+map.D);
```

> 5

Answer (score 3):

```
var alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
    letters = alphabet.split(''),
    len = letters.length,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    window[letters[i]] = Math.ceil((i + 1) / 3);
}

alert(D + D + A);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/dKQS2/